# How to iterate over symfony 2 form children and use them to create a new form?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Lets say i have 2 form types that each has several options in them and i want to then combine those 2 into 1 form as well add some additional fields. I know this can be done using another form type and embedding the forms the problem is that i dont know before hand which 2 form types will be used.

EX:

```
//Controller

$forms = //arbitrary method that gets an array of Symfony\Component\Form\Form's
$masterForm = $this->createFormBuilder();
foreacch($forms as $form){
    //I want to just add the form but this doesnt work,
    $masterForm->add($form);
    //Expected argument of type "string, integer or Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder", "Symfony\Component\Form\Form" given 
}
//Add some final fields before passing it to the view
```

Any help on how to accomplish this will be greatly appreciated.